# 2003 Ford Escape Manual transmission diagnostic

Tags: ford, manual-transmission, escape

Suddenly this morning something happened with my transmission. I was driving out of the driveway when suddenly it seems like the clutch is stuck open. I can shift in and out of gears while the motor is running with the engine on. No previous clutch slippage or issues.

Any ideas on where to start looking?

Comment: I replaced a clutch on an Escape a couple of years back. The friction disk completely lost all of its material. [Here's the image of old vs new.](http://paulster2.com/images/Stuff/20150323_164306.jpg) ... this Escape behaved pretty much as you are describing.

Comment: Can that happen all of a sudden? The clutch was not even slipping before?

Comment: Yes, it can happen all of a sudden. That's what happened to my friend's Escape. It was slipping, but then just ... POOF ... the friction disk gave up the ghost. I'd suggest if this is what happened with yours, it was slipping before and you really weren't noticing it, which could easily happen if you take it easy on your vehicle. I'm not saying this is what happened to your car, but it is surely something which *could have happened*.

Comment: Figured it out ... CV Joint went out

Comment: That'd do it too. I'd expect it to make some noise, though. Glad you got it sorted, though :o) A lot easier than a clutch, that's for sure!

Comment: Thanks! I know, would have thought the same thing ... no warning, and no noise at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, CV Joint went out...